# Create a pdf file out of a html file

Tags: bash, html, wkhtmltopdf

I have a html script

`script.html`

How can I use wkhtmltopdf to create a pdf file out of it?
Should I generate a webpage out of the html file before using wkhtmltopdf ??

Comment: [see details how to use it.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/)

Answer (score 3):

You should read documentation.
In Command Line Interface you should you the command :

```
wkhtmltopdf script.html my.pdf
```

[Link to documentation](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

Answer (score 2):

```
Should I generate a webpage out of the html file before using wkhtmltopdf ??
```

First you have to download web page in html format.For that you can use [wget](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.html) command.

For example

```
wget -p http://your/site/yourpage.html
```

Now  `wkhtmltopdf` syntax is

```
 wkhtmltopdf [html file] [pdf file]
```

Using above syntax you can convert above html file to pdf by

```
wkhtmltopdf yourpage.html yourpage.pdf
```